# parent sources external file, child doesn't have access to functions within

Tags: shell, ksh

Scripts in use: parent.ksh, child.ksh, functions.ksh

When the parent sources functions.ksh, then executes ./child.ksh, the functions within the sourced file are not available to child.ksh.  Is this always true, or does it matter in the way child.ksh was executed?   Child.ksh could source the file, but I'm trying to understand why it isn't working as it's currently configured and how that behavior could be altered.

Read a little about sub-shells and have you invoke different things affects how they behave, but I'm not clear i'm on the right path.

Comment: `Scripts in use: parent.ksh` `sources functions.sh` well, is it `.sh` or `.ksh`? is it bash __or__ ksh?

Comment: Why would anyone name a bash script *.ksh?  They are KSH scripts.

Comment: Well, you stated `functions.sh, then executes ./child.sh` and `to child.sh`. And you tagged bash.

Comment: valid point... I'll update the question

Comment: Functions aren't (normally) part of the environment, so they won't be inherited by other (child) shells.

Comment: Interesting... thought the child inherited the same environment as the parent.  Is this specific to KSH or all/most shell languages?

Comment: The child does inherit the environment.  But functions aren't (normally) part of the environment, so they are not inherited.

Comment: By default. `bash` has an `export -f` capability unless I am misinterpreting something.

Comment: I removed the [tag:bash] tag, but several of the answers you received are for Bash. Perhaps put it back and ask a new question specifically about [tag:ksh]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing on my laptop under git bash -

```
$: cat a
. c
foo from a
./b

$: cat b
foo from b

$: cat c
foo() { echo "$@"; }
foo from c

$: ./a
from c
from a
./b: line 1: foo: command not found
```

However, if I add a line in c:

```
$: cat c
foo() { echo "$@"; }
export -f foo        # export the function named foo
foo from c

$: ./a
from c
from a
from b
```

So, depending on your system, you would need an explicit export of the relevant function name.

Some parsers may not support this. Good luck.

Comment: As KamilCuk mentioned, this is not POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this always true

Functions can't be exported and are not inherited by child process execution environment. Variables are "local" by default and can be marked to be exported with `export`. Functions can't be exported at all - except, Bash shell has an extension to export functions with `export -f`, which is very specific to Bash.

Reference in POSIX: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12 . In short, a subshell != child process.

> , or does it matter in the way child.sh was executed?

It does not matter - if it is executed, a process environment is created that does not include functions.

Answer (score 1):

Like said in other answers, a script sources a file, then the code defined in that sourced file are executed by the shell.

When a script executes another program (being it script or any other program) it is executing in separate process, and does not inherit anything from the internal context of the parent shell.

Environment variables that the parent shell sets (being it anywhere in code (e.g. from sourced file)) before executing a new process are inherited by the new process.

There is a way (may be good if one knows what it is doing) which is creating subshell in `( ... )` and source the `child.sh` there,

like:

```
fn () { echo 'i am fn()'; }

(
 . ./child.sh
)
```

Now if `./child.sh` executes the function `fn` the message `i am fn()` should appear in stdout.

EDIT (2021-07-11): dropped `exit` from the end of ( ... ) section (did anyone notice ?).
The shell (unlike e.g. C/Perl code which forks subprocesses in Unix) waits and reaps subprocesses when not explicitly given `&` to let them run in parallel.